# regexp замена даты в формате d.mm на 0d.mm

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Делаю так:

```
preg_replace( ([0-9]\.), 0$1, "4.12" )
```

результат `04.12`, все как надо.

```
preg_replace( ([0-9]\.), 0$1, "14.12" )
```

результат `104.12` - ошибка. Как указать что одна цифра и точка?

Comment: а у вас строка состоит только из даты? или может быть что-то еще?

Comment: а как вы получаете эту дату? Может проще задать сразу правильный формат?

Comment: в том то и дело, даты в таком формате, изменить нельзя :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы убедится, что число состоит из одной цифры вы можете использовать отрицательное утверждение назад (negative lookbehind):

```
// Выведет "04.12"
echo(preg_replace("/(?<![0-9])([0-9]\.)/", "0$1", "4.12"));

// Выведет "test 04.12"
echo(preg_replace("/(?<![0-9])([0-9]\.)/", "0$1", "test 4.12"));

// Выведет "14.12"
echo(preg_replace("/(?<![0-9])([0-9]\.)/", "0$1", "14.12"));

// Выведет "test 14.12"
echo(preg_replace("/(?<![0-9])([0-9]\.)/", "0$1", "test 14.12"));
```

Подробнее об утверждениях можно почитать в [документации PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.assertions.php).

**UPD:**

Если исходная строка состоит *только из даты*, то можно использовать привязку к началу строки. Этот метод имеет ограниченную область применения, но несколько проще для понимания:

```
// Выведет 14.12
echo(preg_replace("/^([0-9]\.)/", "0$1", "14.12"));
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло в понимании!

Answer (score 2):

А можно просто сделать то, что хочется:

```
sscanf("4.12", "%d.%d", $d, $m);
$str = sprintf("%02d.%02d", $d, $m);
```

Comment: Хороший метод, но в общем случае (если строка состоит не только из даты) не сработает.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev Строку форматирования можно поменять. А главное - что есть выбор.

Comment: Так я же и не спорю)

Answer (score 1):

Если строка не содержит ничего кроме даты, то можно сделать `"/^(\d\.\d\d)/"`.

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо!

Comment: Блестящий ответ! (+1)